# Name error with f-strings in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

I am using the following f-strings in a web application. When I run it locally (before trying on the web) I am getting a name error:

NameError: name 'path' is not defined

But path prints properly and seems to be defined to my mind. What am I doing wrong?

```
path = f'{PROJECT_PATH["raw_data"]}/cashValues'
print("PATH", path)
filenames = [f'{path}/{i}' for i in filenames]
```

Thanks

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/TableTransform.py", line 8, in <module>
    class TableTransform(object):
  File "scripts/TableTransform.py", line 14, in TableTransform
    Filenames = [f'{path}/{i}' for i in filenames]
  File "scripts/TableTransform.py", line 14, in <listcomp>
    Filenames = [f'{path}/{i}' for i in filenames]
NameError: name 'path' is not defined
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem with the information given. Assuming `PROJECT_PATH` and `filenames` are properly defined, this shouldn't give any errors. If you actually run just these three lines after setting reasonable values for those, do you actually still get the error?

Comment: Are you sure the error is happening here? Can you provide the full traceback?

Comment: Yes its super odd. I cannot think why. As mentioned the print statement prints out the path exactly as I expect it to with the correct value. The path is correctly specified. I added the full traceback

Comment: Try `path = f'{PROJECT_PATH["raw_data"]}//cashValues'`

Comment: Sorry, yes that worked nicely! It just needed some "" around "raw_data"

Comment: what is `cashValues`.? A variable name.? or name of a folder.?

Comment: Sorry no that did not work, all that does is set the path as "path"

Comment: Cash Values is a directory

Comment: It works when I enter it directly into ipython but does not work when i run the whole script

Comment: It does not work when I do this either `[os.path.join(path, i) for i in filenames]`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that list comprehension in python 3.6.5 has its own scope and is not aware of variables outside of that scope. This is why it was failing.